# Is possible to declare multiple times same name variable in c# within Ne-stead/same Scope?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

```
namespace project1
{
    public class testclass
    {
        int i = 0;

        public int foobar()
        {
            int i = 1;
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

> 1

I am declaring two times of `i` variable. Why does c# compiler allowing me this ?

If I will try to declare in same scope then compiler will give me exception so why allowing in nested scope?

Comment: It is not a bug of C#. read about local variables and scopes

Comment: *Why* do you expect this to give you an error?

Comment: To expand on the previous comment - the `if` has its own scope (which can also access the enclosing scope). It's a feature that many programming languages have

Comment: @UnholySheep This has more to do with the variable being in the method than it does in the `if`.  If you declare `int i;` at the beginning of the method you cannot declare it again inside of the `if`.

Answer (score 3):

**This is not a bug**

Your field `int i` in the class declaration can be accessed at any time with `this.i` so there is no overlap. In fact, this is actually the convention to write (private) field names, parameters and local variables within methods in camelCase. Properties, method names, class names etc. on the other hand are written in PascalCase.

So in your class if you want to access the field `i` of your class, you can do so by writing `this.i`. Otherwise you will access the scope designated variable `i` as long as you are within the `if`-block.

```
namespace Project1 // PascalCase here for namespace name
{
    public class TestClass // Again PascalCase for class name.
    {
        int i = 0; // camelCase correct here for field name.

        public void Foobar() // PascalCase for method name.
        {
            if (0 == 0)
            {
                int i = 0; // camelCase correct here for local variable name. 
                           // Cannot be re-declared until your if-block is finished.

                // accessing both elements named 'i'
                this.i = i;
            }

        return;
        }
    }
}
```

See [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

All variables declared in a particular scope have to be unique.

You can reuse some variables depending on their data types, but whether or not you should reuse a variable depends on what you're doing.

Your code can work, but you're declaring `i` a second time which is incorrect as it already exists with a value of 0.

You need to change its value instead of trying to recreate the variable:

```
namespace project1
{
    public class testclass
    {
        int i = 0;

        public void foobar()
        {
            if (0 == 0)
            {
                i = 0;
            }

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also create a new variable:

```
namespace project1
{
    public class testclass
    {
        int i = 0;

        public void foobar()
        {
            if (0 == 0)
            {
                int j = 0;
            }

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP is not recreating any variable. inside the `foobar` method a further local varible is created. This is entirely legal. I agree with Mischa, that it is wrong when you say that it is incorrect.

Comment: @MischaBehrend if I'm wrong, how about making yourself useful not only to me but also to every other person who sees this answer and correcting me. The reason OP is having problems is because he's trying to declare a new integer called `i` in the `if` statement but he's also declaring `i` as a global field so `i` already exists without being declared again in the if statement.

Comment: look... OP does not have an problems compiling his code... 'cause it's total legal. And his question is "why is it legal" not "why can't I do". so you already misunderstood the question... And as explanation why you are wrong I'll just point you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45216936/4273199)